# Pushover shell script to send results of command line output to Pushover.app

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script

I am trying to create/edit a pushover shell script that can be called from any script or command, and send the output of the script or command to my Pushover account. Following the instructions on this [page](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-pushover-to-get-notifications-sent-to-your-android-device-from-your-linux-servers/#postComments).

I have placed the following shell script in `/usr/local/bin` and added my app token and user tokens.

I am not getting any pushover notifications, or errors after using this command:

```
john$ ls | pushover.sh 2>&1 | tee file /Users/john/Desktop/results.txt
```

Contents of the shell script EDITED per Glenn

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
         
# TOKEN INFORMATION 
_token='APPTOKEN'
_user='USERTOKEN'
         
# Bash function to push notification to registered device
push_to_mobile() {
  local t="${1:cli-app}"
  local m="$2"
  [[ -n "$m" ]] && curl -s \
    --form-string "token=${_token}" \
    --form-string "user=${_user}" \
    --form-string "title=$t" \
    --form-string "message=$m" \
    https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
}
```

I am assuming the conflict is in the first line, possibly in the quoting, but after trying a few different variations haven't had any success.

An example of what is working after trying to debug the above shell script. Obviously this is to just prove that my pushover settings are all in order. This narrows the issue down to the function in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# TOKEN INFORMATION
_token='xxxx'
_user='yyyy'
_message='test'

# Bash function to push notification to registered device
curl -s \
  --form-string "token=${_token}" \
  --form-string "user=${_user}" \
  --form-string "message=${_message}" \
 https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
```

Comment: Indeed. You need to separate the shell commands with newlines or semicolons. If you were not redirecting stderr, you'd see something like ``bash: local: `[[': not a valid identifier``

Comment: Thanks. Actually before I redirected to stderr, to troubleshoot, I didn't see something like that. Could you rewrite a portion or the entire thing as an answer below?

Comment: Hi, I see the confusion. It's just how I formatted it on this site. Not sure why it has been double indented. I will fix it so it represents my shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the first line of the function is problematic. You need to separate the shell commands with newlines or semicolons. If you were not redirecting stderr, you'd see something like `` bash: local: `[[': not a valid identifier ``

Try this:

```bsh
push_to_mobile() {
  local t="${1:cli-app}"
  local m="$2"
  [[ -n "$m" ]] && curl -s \
    --form-string "token=${_token}" \
    --form-string "user=${_user}" \
    --form-string "title=$t" \
    --form-string "message=$m" \
    https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
}
```

Although I'd use an array for the curl options for easier maintenance.

```bsh
push_to_mobile() {
  [[ -z "$2" ]] && return
  local curl_opts=(
    --silent
    --form-string "title=${1:-cli-app}"
    --form-string "message=$2"
    --form-string "token=${_token}"
    --form-string "user=${_user}"
  )
  curl "${curl_opts[@]}" https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
}
```

---

Demonstrating the error message:

```bsh
$ f() { local a=b local c=d [[ x == x ]] && echo hello; }
$ f
bash: local: `[[': not a valid identifier
bash: local: `==': not a valid identifier
bash: local: `]]': not a valid identifier
```